# Model is flickering and lost in FORGE Viewer using Allocate Memory for Large Models

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I load a model in FORGE Viewer using Allocate Memory for Large Models it flickers while rotating or zooming and some of the parts are lost as picture below.

[Lost parts in FORGE Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KmPZ.png)

Do you have any advice to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use SVF2. For large models only SVF2 works better.
Refer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/notes/